# Xamarin.Forms - How to redirect to last opened directory for file/image/video picker

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, media, imagepicker

I am using xam.plugins.media nuget pkg for image picking. I need to ask if there's a way to open/redirect to the last opened/recent directory? every time user is directed to main galley directory. I want if user opened a directory of camera/dcim/ via image picker and choose a file from it and again he opens the image picker then the camera/dcim directory should open.

I googled it but unable to find anything related.

So any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: There is no such a function in this plugin . You need to implement it by yourself or use the plugin https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT in your mentioned plugin, unable to find that too

Comment: We could not re-set the default path if we use the plugin. If you do want to implement it , you need to implement it by yourself (you could using dependencyservice and implement it on specific platform).By the way, in iOS we could only display all photos or show the album list.